# Pardot and Salesforce Standard Field Integration challenge

Tags: pardot

To integrate our Pardot Prospect country field with our Salesforce Contact/Lead country fields in Salesforce, we select the default text CRM field name: MailingCountry.

I have since discovered our MailingCountry field uses a picklist where the Integration Value is ALLCAPS, eg: FRANCE. Since Pardot is case-sensitive, when ALLCAPs values are returned to Pardot from Salesforce, Pardot discerns this as a new value, eg: was France and is now FRANCE.

On its own this is not catastrophic. However, the challenge we have is this impacts Progressive Profiling since the Prospect would have added, for example, "France" during the form submission and should not be required to enter that information again - but now CRM has changed the value to "FRANCE" which breaks the Progressive Profiling and forces the Prospect to re-enter their country.

I was wondering whether anyone else has encountered this challenge and whether a solution has been found?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pardot and CRM need to have the same VALUEs for Country. You can leverage the ability to give picklist values a different label in Pardot as an easy fix.

In tricky situations like this, we find that having a Custom Pardot field for Country can help, though it is a bit more burdensome.

- Form uses Custom Country field, which you have control over the format
- Another process copies the Custom Country field in its format to the standard Country field in the format expected by the CRM. (We have a product that facilitates this, though it could be built in an Engagement Studio Program or other means).
- Sync to CRM happens with no issue (sync Errors)

It will take a bit of experimentation for you to find the right solution, as everybody's org is a bit different.